# Filestream, locking and serlialization

Tags: c#

I need to open a file, deserialize a List<> of objects, remove one of the objects from the list and re-serialize the List<> back to the file without releasing a lock on the file.

Deserialization and removal of the object from the List<> is no problem, the problem comes when I try and serialize the List<> back to the file as I get the remains of the previous data... anybody any idea how to remove the remaining old data at the end of the file?

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a database. SQL Server Express 2008 is free, and has rich support for XML columns.

Comment: Hi John.  If I had written the spec then this it what I would have used, unfortunately I didn't so I have to make do with files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the remains of the previous data

I assume that you open the file with read/write access, and that you keep it open between deserialization and serialization ? You need to :

- Open the file as read only, deserialize your data, and close the file
- Open the file as write only (without appending to it), serialize your data, and close the file

---

UPDATE:

> How do I keep the file locked between these two seperate operations?

Good point... in that case you could try to truncate the stream while it is open, using SetLength :

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    data = Deserialize(fs);
    DoSomething(data);

    // Truncate the file :
    fs.SetLength(0)
    fs.Position = 0;

    Serialize(fs, data);
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: How do I keep the file locked between these two seperate operations?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, your code works perfectly as you've written it.  Funny how somtimes the answers are so simple you miss them (in this case the SetLength() method).  Thanks again, Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file as (FileMode.Truncate) when writing your serialized data back to the file. This will ensure that the file is completely overwritten by your new data and you do not end up with remnants of the existing data.

See "FileMode.Truncate":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(VS.85).aspx

Additionally, I would recommend using [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) to use as your serialization engine. It's a faster and (in some cases such as obfuscation) more reliable serialization system.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but how do I keep the file locked between these two seperate operations?

Comment: Do you have control of all processes writing to the file? If so, then use a mutex for synchronization: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately I have no control over the proccess(s) writing to the file.